# How can I removed android TV compatibility with my android app?

Tags: java, android

I created an android app, how can I remove android tv compatibility from it so it won't show up for android tv and android wear users in the google play store? I am using android studio.

Comment: Show you efforts.What you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Android World. Just to simplify things: you can relax, your app will not have TV or WEAR versions on Play Store. By now, you can trust me. To know all the details, search for it on the web.

From de "code" point of view of your app, to where this site is dedicated, you have to have three **.apk** files, each of one dedicated to specific hardware, none of them can run outside its projected environment, i.e.: nobody can make a **wear** app run inside an **android tv**, for example and so forth.

Comment: ... er... and, please! Don't forget to check my answer as correct if you think it was helpful in order to put you on the correct way. Thanks!